# Variable number of arguments for newcommand, to create a set containing all of them

Tags: macros

I am relatively new to LaTeX and I am trying to come up with a way of a creating a command, call it `\Set`, such that

```
\Set{#1,#2, #3, ... #N} outputs \tau_{#1} = \{ #2, #3, ... #N \}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: How about an interface that matches `\Set{#1}{#2,#3,#4,...,#N}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend just using two parameters where `#1` is the set name and `#2` is the members of the set:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
    \tau_{#1} = \{#2\}%
}
\begin{document}
$\Set{X}{A,B,C,D}$
\end{document}
```